# How to change x-axis labels in a report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a trend report, in which the x-axis labels are first laywr as year (2014), second quarter (1,2), third period (month) (3,1), fourth week (3,4,5,1,2).

I need to change these labels as `y2014` for year, `Q1,Q2` for quarter, `month3,month1` for month, and `W3,W4,W5` etc. for week.

All I need is to change the labels as they appear.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot that demonstrates the issue? I don't quite follow what's going on.

Comment: I figured it out. If any one would like to know. I will post the answer

Comment: I have a trending graph which shows years as one line above that comes Quarter and above that come fiscal Month, and above that comes week. I would like to show the labels as Y2014 instead of 2014 for year and Q1 as QUarter instead of 1 and month as M3 ,M4 instead of 3,4.

Comment: The work around for this is go to category group properties and ="W" & Fields!Week.Value give this exp in label,group properties and as well as sorting level too, then the result displays the way are showing as above(W1,W2,W4 etc)